# Insecure HTTP-Streaming with Flash on secure website

Tags: flash, video, ssl, streaming, certificate

I'm running a secure website with a valid SSL certificate and I'm embedding a flash player to be able to stream video data via HTPP adaptive bitrate streaming. Problem is that the host of the video contents is a non-secure host, serving the contents via HTTP.
If I now load my page, everything is good, the browser (Chrome) shows the certificate as valid. But if click the play button in the flash player it requests from the unsecure video host and the browser displays the webpage as insecure, too. Is there any way to allow the request from an ssl page to a normal HTTP page via flash without causing this security error?

Thanks!